# Grails Rendering Plugin gives java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when deployed

Tags: grails

I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.icodeya.com/2012/09/grails-how-do-i-render-gsp-files-in-pdf.html) successfully and works good on localhost. It's about using the using the grails rendering plugin. It works good and all on LOCALHOST, but when I deploy the app, or even just run grails run-war, the rendering plugin no longer works. It's giving some weird error. :(

I'm using grails 2.0.0 with rendering plugin 0.4.3 and this is what my BuildConfig.groovy contains:

```
plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.5"
        compile ":rendering:0.4.3"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    }
```

The error is this:

```
2012-09-27 17:08:47,714 [http-8643-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ClassNotFoundException occurred when processing request: [GET] /profile/renderFormPDF/1
org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.init(RenderEnvironment.groovy:33)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:69)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:61)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.generateXhtml(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:68)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:38)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:34)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:33)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:63)
    at com.icodeya.ProfileController.renderFormPDF(ProfileController.groovy:108)
    at net.stax.appserver.webapp.RequestMonitorValve.invoke(RequestMonitorValve.java:35)
    at net.stax.appserver.admin.StaxApplicationQueryValve.invoke(StaxApplicationQueryValve.java:49)
    at net.stax.appserver.webapp.RequestSetupValve.invoke(RequestSetupValve.java:31)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: I've got the same problem and no solution for that (deployed war on appfog / cloudfoundry )

Answer (score 35):

That's in the spring-test jar which is in the dev environment but isn't included in the WAR file. Add

```
runtime 'org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.0.RELEASE'
```

to the `dependencies` section of BuildConfig.groovy.

Comment: Thanks Burt, found this solution also solved a similar problem when using the mail 1.0.3 plugin.

Comment: If you are using Grails 2.3.7, use `org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.8.RELEASE` since is the dependant for _org.grails:grails-plugin-testing:2.3.7_

Comment: For the version of Grails you're using, run "grails dependency-report" and find the dependencies for org.grails:grails-plugin-testing. One of them should be org.springframework:spring-test:x.x.x.RELEASE and use that.

Comment: In my case this problem happens when I use the rendering plugin together with the Standalone plugin. To Grails 2.4.3 I use the following version: runtime 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.6.RELEASE' and it works like a charm.